# Rendering a dynamic ListView and passing key to method

Tags: javascript, listview, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to render a ListView with a dynamic amount of switches so in my _renderRow function I did the following : (list contains a key, value array)

```
_renderRow(list) {
    var jsxList = [];

    for (var k in list) {
      jsxList.push(
        <View>
          <Text>{list[k]}</Text>
          <Switch value={this.state.switches[k]} onValueChange={() => this._changeValue(k)}/>
        </View>
      )
    }

    return (
      <View>
        {jsxList}
      </View>
    )
}
```

My problem is that when I trigger the switch, the key sent to _changeValue is always the last of my list even though when I pushed it to my array it wasn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, variables declared using `var` gets [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting), so when `_changeValue(k)` runs, `k` will always be the last value it was assigned to. You can solve this using a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures):

```
for (var k in list) {
  (function () {
    jsxList.push(
      <View>
        <Text>{list[k]}</Text>
        <Switch value={this.state.switches[k]} onValueChange={() => this._changeValue(k)}/>
      </View>
    )
  }())
}
```

Or, if you use ES6, you can use `let` to create a block scoped variable:

```
for (let k in list) {
  jsxList.push(
    <View>
      <Text>{list[k]}</Text>
      <Switch value={this.state.switches[k]} onValueChange={() => this._changeValue(k)}/>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach could be to use the `map` method instead of the `for..in` loop:

```
_renderRow(list) {
    var jsxList = list.map((item, k) => {
      return (  
        <View>
          <Text>{item}</Text>
          <Switch value={this.state.switches[k]} onValueChange={() => this._changeValue(k)}/>
        </View>
      );
    }

    return (
      <View>
        {jsxList}
      </View>
    )
}
```